# How to write a simpler makefile for a lot of single-c-file programmes?

Tags: makefile

I want to write a lot of tiny example programmes for one same library, each needs `gcc $(OtherOpt) -o xxx -lthelibname xxx.c`.

How to write a Makefile without dozens of tagret lines ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern rules are your friend for these situations.  As long as your targets all match a predictable pattern -- and they do in this case, as they are all of the form "create `foo` from `foo.c`" -- you can write a single pattern rule that will be used for all of the targets:

```
OtherOpt=-Wall -g
all: $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard *.c))
%: %.c
        gcc $(OtherOpt) -o $@ -lthelibname $<
```

Now you can either run simply `make` to build all your apps, or `make appname` to build a specific app.  Here I've created a single pattern rule that will be used anytime you want to create `something` from `something.c`.  I used the `$@` automatic variable, which will expand to the name of the output, and the `$<` variable, which will expand to the name of the first prerequisite, so that the command-line is correct regardless of the specific app being built.  Technically you don't need the `all` line, but I figured you probably didn't want to *always* have to type in the name(s) of the apps you want to build.

Also, technically you can probably get away without having *any* of this makefile, because GNU make already has a built-in pattern rule for the `%: %.c` relationship!  I mention this option only for completeness; personally, I prefer doing things the way I've shown here because it's a little bit more explicit what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
%.o: %.c
    gcc $(OtherOpt) -c -o $@ -lthelibname $<
```

That compiles all .c files to their .o files (object code) of the same base name.  Then in your actual target(s), you would include all necessary .o files as dependencies and use `gcc $(OtherOpt) -o $@ $^ -lthelibname`, assuming I'm not misunderstanding how your build is set up.

Some versions of make also support the suffix rule `.c.o` to be ALMOST the same thing as `%.o: %.c`, but the suffix rules can't have any dependencies.  Writing `.c.o: foo.h` tells make to compile "foo.h" to "foo.c.o" rather than requiring "foo.h" as a dependency of any file with a .c suffix as `%.o: %.c foo.h` would correctly do.

Comment: Each c file contains enough code for a individual target. And I want to get all the targets with a single rule.

Answer (score 1):

I learnd from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcmakefile/

```
LDLIB     = -lpthread
LDFLAGS   = -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--hash-style=both $(LDLIB)
SRCDIRS   =

SRCEXTS = .c .C .cc .cpp .CPP .c++ .cxx .cp

CFLAGS  = -pipe -march=core2 -mtune=generic -Wfloat-equal \
#-Wall -pedantic

ifeq ($(SRCDIRS),)
  SRCDIRS = .
endif
SOURCES = $(foreach d,$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*,$(SRCEXTS))))
TARGET  = $(addprefix bin/,$(basename $(SOURCES)))

all: $(TARGET)
    ls -l $(TARGET)

bin/%: %.c dir
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

dir:
    @-mkdir bin

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    -rm $(TARGET)
    -rmdir bin
```